# JsHelper and Ajax not working in Cakephp

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I seriously can' understand what is going on here !The Jquery is not working at all ! The script is getting generated and everything. but when I click on the submit button it follows the same process as without jquery and ajax.
Please help ! thanks.
Here is my, Controller:

```
class MessagesController extends AppController{

    public  $helpers=array('Js'=>array('Jquery'));
    public $components = array('RequestHandler');

    public function index(){
        if(!empty($this->data)){
            if($this->Message->save($this->data)){
                if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){
                    $this->render('success','ajax');
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Ajax');   
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

?>
and here is my View:

```
<?php echo  $this->Html->script('jquery',FALSE); ?>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create();
echo $this->Form->input('name',array('id'=>'id'));
echo $this->Form->input('email',array('id'=>'email'));
echo $this->Form->input('message',array('id'=>'message'));
echo $this->Js->submit('Submit',array(
'before'=>$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeIn') ,
'success'=>$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeOut'),
'update'=>'#success'
 ));
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
<div id="sending" style="display:none;background-color:green" >Sending...</div>
<div id="success"></div>
```

This is the javascript file being generate,

```
$("#submit-84782947").bind("click", function (event) {$.ajax({beforeSend:function                   (XMLHttpRequest) {$("#sending").fadeIn();}, complete:function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {$("#sending").fadeOut();}, data:$("#submit-84782947").closest("form").serialize(),   dataType:"html", success:function (data, textStatus) {$("#success").html(data);},       type:"post", url:"\/Cake\/messages"});
```

return false;});

As I noticed there is no $(document).ready stuff in the generate file, could that be the problem ?

Comment: which CakePHP version are you using..?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
echo $this->Js->submit('Submit',array(
  'before' => $this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeIn', array('buffer' => false)),
  'complete' => $this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeOut', array('buffer' => false)),
   'update' => '#success'

));
//if that doesnot work then checkout:
```

[CakePHP Ajax Helper](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/jozek000/2011/11/23/ajax_helper_with_jquery_for_cakephp_2_x)

Hope it helps

Comment: I am using the latest one ! I am very new to the framework.
Nup ! It still does not work. I even copied the exact same code that was given in this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQ71psonQx0
and now when I click on the submit button it takes me to a blank page ! The entries are getting saved in the database but nothing else is happening.

Comment: you could use ajax helper for cakePHP 2.0, see the link above.. hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

> Since the JsHelper automatically buffers all generated script content
>   to reduce the number of  tags in your source code you **must**
>   call write the buffer out. At the bottom of your view file. Be sure to
>   include:

```
<?php
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
```

> If you omit this you will not be able to chain ajax pagination links.
>   When you write the buffer, it is also cleared, so you don’t have worry
>   about the same Javascript being output twice.

[CakePHP 2.0 cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html#making-ajax-links)

Comment: Is this possible to add another success ??

'success'=>$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeOut'),
'success'=>$this->Js->get('#load')->effect('fadeIn'),

Answer (score 0):

in cakephp 2.3 `$this->RequestHandler->isAjax()` is deprecated and is now `$this->Request->isAjax()` 
am trying to do the same thing using this view file:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create(); echo $this->Form->input('name');echo $this->Form->input('email'); echo $this->Form->input('phone'); echo $this->Form->input('message');   echo $this->Js->submit('Send Enquiry', array(
    'before' => $this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeIn'),
    'success' => $this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeOut'),
             'update' => '#success',
              'async' => true
               ));echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

and this controller function:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Contact->create();
        if ($this->Contact->save($this->request->data)) {

            if($this->request->isAjax()){
                $this->autoRender = false;  
                echo 'successful';
                }else{
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The contact has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                }
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The contact could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
}
```

at the end, the data is saved to database but i can't get response to the client side so i help too on this